# Delegating between UIViews - where to put the receiver's delegate?

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, delegates

I have two views:

1. Delegating view with a "Send" button that when pressed invokes a sendMessage via delegation
2. Receiving view with a label. Upon receiving the sendMessage, the label should change.

For some reason, I can't get them to "connect". I suspect that it has something to do with how the receivers delegate is set (which is usually the case when the sender's delegate is nil as it is in this case). But where to put it? I have searched the web, books, etc for this answer and though it is occasionally asked, it is never answered. What am I missing here?

Seems like has something to do with the "receiver.delegate = self" line.

Here are the two UIViews:

Sending:

```
import UIKit

protocol DelegatingViewDelegate {
func sendMessage()
}

class DelegatingView: UIView {

var delegate: DelegatingViewDelegate?


init() {

    super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100))
}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
}

@IBOutlet weak var delegatingLabel :UILabel?

@IBAction func sendButton(sender: AnyObject) {
    print(delegate)
   delegate?.sendMessage()
    print("Sending message")

}

}
```

Receiving:

```
import UIKit

class ReceivingView: UIView, DelegatingViewDelegate {

var receiver = DelegatingView()

init() {

    super.init(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 100))
    receiver.delegate = self

}

required init(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    super.init(coder: aDecoder)!
}

override func awakeFromNib() {
    //
}

@IBOutlet weak var receiveingLabel :UILabel?

func sendMessage() {


    receiveingLabel?.text = "GOT IT"
    print("Received message")
}

}
```

Comment: You don't show anywhere where you set the delegate.  You would have to do this in the view controller. In fact, it is probably the view controller that should be the delegate and it should update the text field.

Comment: Okay, I can delegate to the view controller and set the text field of the view by setting the delegate in view controller.  But that is indirect communication and really isn't what I was looking for. Can't I get the two views to "talk" to each other? Is this some sort of MVC violation? I thought that delegation was the way to get "around" these issues. Why doesn't receiver.delegate = self work (and it clearly doesn't)

Comment: What you are doing is violating MVC. The challenge you have is that the delegate needs a reference to the delegator in order to set itself as the delegate. Now your view controller will have references to both items so it can say something like `self.view1.delegate=self.view2.delegate`

Answer (score 0):

See Paulw11's comment. I was trying to break the MVC and Xcode was fighting back.

So the solution is to go through the view controller and place some code like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, DelegatingViewDelegate {

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    delegatingView.delegate = self

}

@IBOutlet weak var delegatingView: DelegatingView!
```

in the view controller. Note that in the above snippet the delegatingView had been set as an outlet and I can set the text label through it.